# Initializer list in a range for loop

Tags: c++, c++11, for-loop, range, initializer-list

I have objects of different types derived from a single super-type. I wonder if there are any disadvantages in using `std::initializer` list in a range for loop like this:

```
for(auto object: std::initializer_list<Object *>{object1, object2, object3}) {
}
```

Is it completely OK and efficient or would it be better to use an array? To me the `std::array` solution seems to be more restrictive for the compiler and there is a disadvantage of explicitly stating the size:

```
for(auto object: std::array<Object*, 3>{object1, object2, object3}) {
}
```

Is there any other or nicer way of iterating over an explicitly given list of objects?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is no need to use the verbose `std::initializer_list` inside the loop

```
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>

struct B { virtual int fun() { return 0; } };
struct D1 : B { int fun() { return 1; } };
struct D2 : B { int fun() { return 2; } };

int main()
{
    D1 x;
    D2 y;

    B* px = &x;
    B* py = &y;

    for (auto& e : { px, py })
            std::cout << e->fun() << "\n";    
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8095af0fb8097788).

If you want to do it on-the-fly without defining `px` and `py`, you can indeed use `std::initializer_list<B*>{ &x, &y }` inside the loop.

Comment: That does not seem to work for me. As I wrote objects are of different types with a common super-type: http://ideone.com/4KtpQw

Comment: @JurajBlaho try writing `{&a, {&b}}`

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: It only works if at least one element is of the base (target) type, but nice trick anyway.

Comment: A bit shorter workaround: `for (auto& e : { static_cast<B*>(&x), {&y} })`

Answer (score 12):

You can simply write

```
for(auto object : {object1, object2, object3}) {
   // work
}
```

Comment: What is the name of the `{ obj, obj }` thing? Is that just an initializer list, or is there a special name for it?

Comment: Of course, this can only be used as-is if (A) `objectN`s are definitely pointers already (otherwise inefficient, object slicing, only updating a temporary copy of the real element, etc.), and (B) the objects are of a common type as noted above; base/derived combinations need the verbose syntax AFAICT. @TankorSmash It's a _braced init-list_ that can be deduced to various types, but `std::initializer_list` is given top priority.

Comment: Is order maintained while traversing or is it not defined?